# Will apache Ignite identify the current host and port of webservice it is used in by itself?

Tags: spring-boot, ignite

What kind of configuration should be used to make the apache ignite used in a restful webservice to identify itself the host and port wherever it is deployed.
I could see directly giving host and port name in the example-ignite.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Ignite doesn't know whether it's in web service or not. You need to configure your own web service, for example, using `jetty` + `jersey` and call Ignite API from it when it's needed:

[Ignite Spring Boot integration example](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-integration-with-apache-ignite-and-its), [Spring Boot REST service example](http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-api-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Ignite also comes with it's own REST API:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api